# how to install mycli in alpine

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

I am using this command to install mycli in alpine but failed:

```
bash-4.4# apk add mycli
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  mycli (missing):
    required by: world[mycli]
```

how to install successfully in alpine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mycli`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=mycli&branch=edge) package is currently only available in the `edge/testing` repository.

Therefore, you'd have to specify that repository to apk explicitly:

```
apk add mycli --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```